# Gridview with expandible rows for winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

i'm looking for a gridview with expansible rows for a winforms.

maybe free..

Any tips?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found this cool solutions for winforms

ObjectListView (my favorite)
http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html

SourceGrid
http://sourcegrid.codeplex.com/

OutlookGrid
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/OutlookGrid.aspx

hope this helps