# Trouble with refreshing Data Grid View

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, datagridview, refresh

I've been having a lot of trouble displaying all the records I have in a Data Grid View Control. I'm using unbound data to populate my grid since there are not many records to display and I need that data to be read only. My issue is that when I populate my grid programatically, not all rows are displayed and they're only displayed when I try resizing the header column width. I tried different things like Refresh, Invalidate, etc to make the grid display all records but nothing worked! I would really appreciate any insight on why this happens and how to solve it!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try to display your records with other controls
look at my answer for this question

[Gridview with expandible rows for winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179222/gridview-with-expandible-rows-for-winforms)

can you post some code to reproduce teh problem?

best regards